# mysqli select all rows starting with letter

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm converting all MySQL to MySQLi pages. I need to select all rows where a column starts with a letter.

On MySql If I want all rows starting with P, I used to add % to P, so I'll search all entries LIKE P%, but it's not working on MySQLi

If $type = P%

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column LIKE $type");

I get no results.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting quotes around the variable in the query so that it looks like this :

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column LIKE '$type'");
```

This will probably solve the problem.

Comment: Wow. I thought I have had tried that, but I guess I didn't. Thank you!!